# How can I add capability to multiple roles?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I have this variable:

```
$wpll_accesslist = self::$options['wpll_settings']['wpll_accesslist'];
```

and it's output is:

```
Array
(
    [Author] => 1
    [Contributor] => 1
    [Shop_Manager] => 1
    [Customer] => 1
)
```

These **Author, Contributor, Shop_Manager, Customer** is roles. Now, I want to add new capability called **wpll_caps** to these roles.

What I am doing for this:

```
foreach($wpll_accesslist as $key => $value) {
    // get the the role object
    $role_object = get_role( strtolower($key) );
    // add wpll_caps capability to this role object
    $role_object->add_cap( 'wpll_caps' );
}
```

but it's not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a reason you want a multi dimensional array to be used?

Comment: How is your code being called? When is it called? And how are you confirming if it worked/didn't work?